# What happened in Southeast Asia in these years?

Tags: economy, south-east-asia

Im interesting to know what happened in the GDP growth in those years. I think that the 1964 and 1978 decline was because of the fall in oil prices, but im not sure. And in 1970 i really don't know what happened, maybe it was because of the high oil prices, but a lot of countries in the southeast asia export oil.
Thank you.
[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused here. Your question says Southeast Asia (commonly meaning Vietnam, Laos, Cambodia, Thailand, Myanmar, Malaysia,  Indonesia, Singapore, Philippines, East Timor, Brunei + a few other islands), while the data is for South Asia (commonly meaning  Afghanistan, Bangladesh, Bhutan, Maldives, Nepal, India, Pakistan and Sri Lanka).

Comment: Regarding the data, 1965 coincides in time with the Indo-Pakistani War of 1965, in 1972 there is another low point that could be the effects of the Indo-Pakistani War of 1971, and the 1973 low was probably the combination of that with the Oil crisis.

Comment: The downturn in 1979 is probably the [1979 oil shock](https://www.federalreservehistory.org/essays/oil_shock_of_1978_79) that resulted from the Iranian revolution. Pakistan did export oil, I am not certain about Afghanistan, India, Bangladesh, Sri Lanka not so much. If you look at country level data, you will also find that the downturn in 1979 is not there in Pakistan's GDP data (but it is present in India's for instance).